# My MacBook Pro won't exit out of iPhotos

Tags: macbook-pro

I was importing pictures from my Nikon d3200, i had to stop it early, so i pressed the stop importing, and the delete the pictures that you have already imported, then I left. Now, it won't close out of iPhotos and it says it is importing photos, but it said that all day. Since it won't close out, i can't shut down my Mac or restart it. And I can't import the rest of my photos either. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to exit an application that is stuck:

Hold <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> and then Force quit the application that is not responding.

If that did not work force shutdown the computer by holding the power button for 5 seconds or longer.

In both case you will lose all unsaved information.